# Functions in GAMS

Tags: optimization, model, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization, gams-math

In GAMS, I need to put an equation in a function. Look at this example

```
$ontext
minimize 5x^2+3x-12
subject to
4x+2x^2<10
$offtext

variable OF, x;
equation obj,cons;
obj .. OF=E=5*x*x+3*x-12;
cons .. 4*x+2*x*x=L=10;
model this /all/;
solve this using NLP maximizing OF;
display x.l,OF.l,cons.l;
```

The solution is

```
VARIABLE x.L                   =        1.449  
VARIABLE OF.L                  =        2.854  
EQUATION cons.L                =       10.000
```

Now, let say I want to define the objective as a function:

```
f(x)=5x^2+3x-12
```

and replace the first constraint with

```
obj .. OF=E=f(x);
```

How should I do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure, if I understand your motivation to do this, but what you could do, is using a macro like this:

```
variable OF, x;
equation obj,cons;

$macro f(x) 5*x*x+3*x-12

obj .. OF=E=f(x);
cons .. 4*x+2*x*x=L=10;
model this /all/;
solve this using NLP maximizing OF;
display x.l,OF.l,cons.l;
```